# How to avoid matrices when designing models for multivariate problems?

Tags: model, covariance-matrix, matrix, parameterization

Multivariate mathematical problems are often resolved classically with some form of a model that uses the covariance matrix, or some similar device, to collect statistics of multivariate data into one object. However, the well-known downside of this is that there are so many parameters to estimate within that matrix, making it an approach prone to estimation error.

What are the most common alternatives to such model designs when dealing with multivariate data? The answer can be for any general application that may have classically been assigned a matrix solution, but later was assigned a superior approach that avoids the high parameterization found in the classical way.